# What is the state-of-the-art in ROS navigation with dynamic obstacles?

Tags: ros, navigation, path-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just wanted to know the state-of-the-art in path planners that incorporate dynamic obstacle avoidance. And some of the well known libraries for this sort of stuff.

UPDATE: I'm not talking about local planners like the dynamic window approach that approach dynamic obstacles as a static path planning problem with the additional dimension of time.
I'm looking for approaches like the velocity obstacle and others that model and/or predict the motion of obstacles and plan accordingly.

EDIT: Someone mentioned OMPL and MoveIt! in the comments. But AFAIK, OMPL is only for sampling based planners? And so these are not as useful for field robotics. Also, dynamic obstacle avoidance should involve much more than planning in a static space?

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192287/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-in-ros-navigation-with-dynamic-obstacles?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-17**:
I think [robotics.stackexchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/) is the right forum for this question.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-09-17**:
Sounds good. Thanks!

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-10-24**:
Changed Q to be ROS specific.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-10-27**:
Not sure why this was closed, it seems like a relevant discussion to have.

**Comment by [VEGETA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26893/vegeta/) on 2016-05-28**:
I'd like to know the answer too. If you know anything plz send it here hossam.moghrabi@gmail.com

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any ROS packages that implement 2d navigation with dynamic obstacle avoidance. You may want to expand your search to robotics journals.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2